# Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor using quarters

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I am trying to parse some date-string into a date value, however, using the below code, I am getting an exception:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Q'Q'uuuu - MMM");

String d = "3Q2016 - Aug";
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(d, formatter));
```

The exception is below

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '3Q2016 - Aug' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=8, QuarterOfYear=3, Year=2016},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Looking at the exception, I see the correct data, but it is not able to be parsed for some reason.

Other similar topics i see suggest using LocalDate or LocalDateTime, but neither work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because the specified string does not have a specific date to select. You probably need to use `YearMonth` instead of `LocalDateTime` and then convert it using `YearMonth.atDay(1)` to get the first day of the month.

Comment: Correct. In English locale `YearMonth.parse(d, formatter).atDay(1)` yields `2016-08-01`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that it required to point to a specific date. This pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: @OleV.V. or you [fix the day right in the formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55276153/2711488).

Comment: Yes, @Holger. Or you stick to `YearMonth`. There are many possibilities, and each has its place.

Answer (score 4):

As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55269040/2711488), you need to specify a day to be able to parse to a `LocalDate`. So one solution is to parse to a `YearMonth` instead and convert to a `LocalDate` by specifying a day afterwards.

Or you create a `DateTimeFormatter` with a fixed day in the first place:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("Q'Q'uuuu - MMM")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    .toFormatter(Locale.US);
String d = "3Q2016 - Aug";
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse(d, formatter));
```

I used `toFormatter(Locale.US)` to make the example work in all environments. In an environment where the input string matches the current locale, you can use `toFormatter()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a Time part to the date -

```
String str = "2Q1986 - Apr - 08 T00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("Q'Q'yyyy - MMM - dd 'T'hh:mm");
LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(str, formatter);
```

Comment: While this solution works (and yields `1986-04-08`), adding time of day os overkill when a `LocalDate` is all we want (and get) in the end (I didn’t downvote; I think the answer still contributes something helpful).