# How to parse date from year and quarter using java.time

Tags: java, date, java-time, date-parsing

I am trying to parse strings in the format of "<year> <quarter>" ("2022 1", "2022 2") into java.time.LocalDate objects. The closest related question I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268992/unable-to-obtain-localdate-from-temporalaccessor-using-quarters), but there the author also has the month.
If I try to use

```
DateTimeFormatter quarterFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
.appendPattern("yyyy q")
.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1).toFormatter();
LocalDate.parse("2022 2", quarterFormatter);
```

I get the error `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: (...) Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {Year=2022, QuarterOfYear=2, DayOfMonth=1}` , which doesn't really make sense to me, since that is all the data required to figure out a calendar date.
What am I doing wrong?

Also, as a related question, the original format is actually without a whitespace between the year and the quarter, but if I try to run

```
DateTimeFormatter quarterFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
.appendPattern("yyyyq")
.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1).toFormatter();
LocalDate.parse("20222", quarterFormatter);
```

I get `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20222' could not be parsed at index 0`. That is also confusing, since parsing from other formats seems to work even without separators.

Comment: "since that is all the data required to figure out a calendar date. " <- Not really. Year=2022, QuarterOfYear=2, DayOfMonth=1 could be 2022-04-01, or 2022-05-01 or 2022-06-01. A Quarter isn't a specific month.

Comment: Which day in that quarter do you want? What date do you expect to get for "2022 2"?

Comment: Simply `.parseDefaulting(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1)` instead of the `parseDefaulting` call you have got. You will then get `2022-04-01`, the first day of the 2nd quarter.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter` is not good at separating `yyyy` fields from other fields. For your related question of `20222` you may use `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder() .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4) .appendValue(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR, 1) .parseDefaulting(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1) .toFormatter()`.

Comment: Thank you @OleV.V., I didn't think of using the IsoFields class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a compilation of the information given in the comments:

#### Why do I get the *Unable to obtain LocalDate* message? And how to fix it?

That is because the parser does not have all necessary information, as OH GOD SPIDERS already said:

> Not really. Year=2022, QuarterOfYear=2, DayOfMonth=1 could be 2022-04-01, or 2022-05-01 or 2022-06-01. A Quarter isn't a specific month.

How to fix it, was mentioned by Ole V.V.:

> Simply `.parseDefaulting(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1)` instead of the `parseDefaulting` call you have got. You will then get `2022-04-01`, the first day of the 2nd quarter.

#### How do I fix the *Text '20222' could not be parsed at index 0* error?

As mentioned by Ole V.V.:

> `DateTimeFormatter` is not good at separating `yyyy` fields from other fields. For your related question of `20222` you may use
>
> ```java
> new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
>     .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
>     .appendValue(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR, 1)
>     .parseDefaulting(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1)
>     .toFormatter()
> ```

<sup>(Formatting mine.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Nice to have it presented in a structured and formatted way.

Answer (score 2):

[@OleV.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72042645/how-to-parse-date-from-year-and-quarter-using-java-time#comment127296509_72042645) contains the right solution of using `.parseDefaulting(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1)`.